# Converting iOS app to Android

Tags: android, ios, converters

I am developing an iOS application on swift and I was wondering is it possible to convert the code to run on android devices or I have to develop a new application. I have experience only with writing application on swift and I do not know how to create an android application. If it is possible to convert it it will be great.

Comment: Short answer: no you cannot just convert your app. This question is also too broad, opinion based and asking for tools or other off-site resources and as such it is not suitable for this site. Please visit [help] to learn what kind of questions you can ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to write different code for ios and android. Check if Hybrid app fits your requirements. Check out [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (Adobe phonegap). You will be coding your application as a web app using HTML Css Js. Please be aware of its own pro's and con's of going with hybrid app.

If you are looking for truly native alternatives, Check out [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) which gives you native application's UI, Performance and access to low level API's. You need to code your app in C#

You cannot directly convert swift code to make it work on Android.